# Low (wrong?) temperature on AMD ryzen 1920X

Tags: cpu, temperature, amd-ryzen

I recently built 2 workstations with AMD Ryzen chips : 1920X and 2990WX. I'm running CFD simulation, so I need to load them 100% for long periods of time.

The temperature I get with lm-sensors on ubuntu 18.04 looks normal, even with AMD offsets, on the 2990WX. However **1920X hardly ever exceeds 50°** on large loads. Its fan is a not so large noctua U14. Bios temp and lm-sensors temp are rather **consistent on idle : ~ 25-30°**. They are working on factory settings, no overclocking, on identical ASUS X399 boards.

I think this is too good to be true, and I'm afraid to fry it if there is something wrong with the sensor.

I'd be keen to hear feedbacks from people who either found out wrong temp readings on these chips, or colder than usual operation.

Thanks all !

Comment: It couldn't hurt to call and support. They might have some knowledge.

Comment: You're totally right, here's the answer:

The temperatures you informed are well within the normal and accepted for this CPU which has a maximum temperature of 68°C.
However to confirm that your system is reading the temperatures correctly, I would suggest downloading the Ryzen Master tool:
- https://www.amd.com/en/technologies/ryzen-master
Also notice the TDP for this CPU is 180W. For a cooler to be completely compatible and safe for your CPU, it should meet the 180W TDP requirement.

Well I guess there's nothing to worry about. Impressive compared to my 75°C 7820X !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's actually two different ways to measure processor temperature: via a temperature sensor built into the processor die, or a sensor in the processor package, mounted on the integrated heat spreader. The former measures a value called T<sub>junction</sub>, while the measurement from the latter is called T<sub>case</sub>.

On-die temperature sensors are intended to measure the temperature of the actual silicon but have historically been less accurate than on-package sensors. On-package temperature sensors tend to be better calibrated, but they give lower values that may be less representative of the actual core temperature.

Most (single-die) Ryzen processors report only T<sub>junction</sub> and do not have an on-package temperature sensor. However, because Ryzen Threadripper processors are [multi-chip modules](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multi-chip_module), and each die on the package will have a separate junction temperature, there is a package temperature sensor intended to represent the overall temperature of the processor as a whole. It is this package temperature T<sub>case</sub> that you're seeing.

The maximum allowed T<sub>case</sub> for Threadripper processors, both first and second generation, is 68 °C. As long as you don't exceed this value, you're fine.